# Python regular expressions: return matches in a line rather than list?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am using regular expressions to parse through a log file to extract the different fields to basically make a dataset. The regular expression works fine:

```
import re

example_line = '65.55.106.233 - - [03/Sep/2009:16:31:55 -0800] "GET /gallery/main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=27492&g2_serialNumber=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4457 "-" "Mozilla/4.0"'



print re.match(regex, example_line).groups()
```

output:

```
('65.55.106.233', '-', '-', '03/Sep/2009:16:31:55 -0800', 'GET /gallery/main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=27492&g2_serialNumber=2 HTTP/1.1', '200', '4457', '-', 'Mozilla/4.0')
```

However I was wondering if there was a way to group the matches to a single line separated by a single space instead of grouping the matches in a list.

So instead of the output shown above I would like to print this instead:

```
65.55.106.233 - - 03/Sep/2009:16:31:55 -0800 GET /gallery/main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=27492&g2_serialNumber=2 HTTP/1.1 200 4457 - Mozilla/4.0
```

Comment: Is python 3 an option?

Comment: Why did you edit the question to remove the regex? It's not central to your question, but a rather odd change to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print ' '.join(re.match(regex, example_line).groups())
```

Comment: `print ' '.join(re.match(regex, example_line).groups())`

Comment: @Tim007 - I meant `' '`. I thought I typed `' '`. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

> ### Python < 3.0

I think the ***cleanest*** and most pythonic way to do this with pre-3.0 python is:

```
print ' '.join(map(str, re.match(regex, example_line).groups()))
```

To clean it up a little, you could save the re.match result in a variable:

```
result = re.match(regex, example_line).groups()
print ' '.join(map(str, result))
```

**Example:**

```
>>> result = [7, 8, 9, '10', 11, '12']
>>> print ' '.join(map(str, result))
7 8 9 10 11 12
```

---

> ### Python >= 3.0

Of course, there's always a *nicer* option with Python 3.0+. If using Python 3 isn't an option, you may be able to use `from __future__ import print_function` in your Python 2.x code.

This is the nice Python 3 way of printing a list on one line without the commas:

```
print( *re.match(regex, example_line).groups() )
```

And of course, saving the re.match in a variable makes the code very clean and understandable:

```
result = re.match(regex, example_line).groups()
print( *result )
```

**Example:**

```
>>> result = [7, 8, 9, '10', 11, '12']
>>> print(*result)
7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Comment: @tripleee Py3k adds the spaces automatically.

Comment: Yeah.  If you want a different separator in Python 3 [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print), the `sep=','` optional keyword does that.